# Is there a limit on the length of a Google doc I can save as a Word doc?

Tags: google-docs, download

I have a 600-page document on Google Docs which I would like to save on my desktop as a Word doc, as a back-up.

I go to "File" then "download as" then "Microsoft Word" which is the common way of saving a document from Google to Word. My 600 pages are mostly text and contain about 1-2 photos per page. Unfortunately the first 48 pages are copied each time..

I wonder if perhaps there is a limit as to how much one can copy, and if perhaps 600 pages is too long? If that is not so, can you please advise how to fix this problem, and make a back-up on Word of the entire document.

Comment: Welcome. What do you mean by "your instructions"? What kind of content has your doc? What is the size of the resulting 48 pages docx file?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick response. What I mean by "instructions" is I go to "File" then "download as" then "Microsoft Word" which is the common way of saving a document from Google to Word. My 600 pages are mostly text and contain about 1-2 photos per page. Only the first 48 pages are copied each time...

Comment: Try to download your file from Google Drive. By the way maybe 1-2 photos per page are too much for the download process

Comment: You are probably right about the photo limit. But I was able to copy and paste (it took 2 hrs and changed the formatting by 230 pages) but I now have a back-up of sorts.

Answer (score -1):

**There is no length limit. All you suppose to do is:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is what I've been doing, and only the first 48 pages get copied into the newly created Word doc. Very strange.

Comment: can you share that doc (or copy of it) for further debugging?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's too personal for me to share. But I just discovered that if I do "copy all" and paste it onto a Word doc, then wait 2 hours, the  entire text plus photos copied. The formatting is off the charts and the 600 pages turned into 830, but at least I now have my emergency Word Doc back up on my desk top.